# Dynamic GroupName in Cloudformation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I want to add Stack Names to Security Group Names created with Cloudformation. I mean I would like to add randomize name to the GroupName.

Example:

```
  ELBSecurityGroup:
      Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
      Properties:
        GroupName: ${AWS::StackName} SG
        VpcId: !Ref VpcId
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delete `GroupName: ${AWS::StackName} SG` then your SG group will create with your stack name.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Sub function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html):

```yaml
GroupName: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}SG'
```